# Existence of an open set G such that a continuous function $f:X\to\,\mathbb{Q}$ is constant on G.

Tags: metric-spaces, complete-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ a complete metric space. We have a continuous function $f:X\to\,\mathbb{Q}$ , the rationals. Show that there exists an open set $G$ in $X$ such that $f$ is constant on $G$.

My proof relies on a theorem (not very well known) which has a rather difficult proof, saying that if $X=\bigcup_{n}A_{n}$ with all $A_{n}$ closed, then there is some $A_{n}$ containing an open neighborhood $S(x,\epsilon)$.

Let $\left\{q_{1},q_{2},.... \right\}$ be the sequence of the rational numbers.

Take $A_{n}=f^{-1}\left\{q_{n} \right\}$. Then by continuity each $A_{n}$ is closed.

And it is clear that $X=\bigcup_{n}A_{n}$. By invoking the theorem we get that there is an open neighborhood $S(x,\epsilon)$ in at least one $A_{n}$ and hence $f(x)=q_{n}$ constant on this open neighborhood.

So, the question is, can we find a direct, self-contained proof of the result, without referring to this theorem? I believe it would be something hard to do.

The link of the theorem is [https://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/336_14/papers/alana.pdf](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Emorrow/336_14/papers/alana.pdf)

Comment: What you call a not very well known Theorem is a pretty famous one which is called Baire's Theorem!

Comment: I might be wrong, but I have the feeling that your “theorem” is *equivalent* to the Baire category theorem (which means that there is no “simpler, direct” proof).

Comment: I agree! This is  what I believe. It is much deeper than it seems.

Answer (score 1):

The preimage of a rational number $q$ is a closed subset of $X,$ and by your assumption it has empty interior, so is nowhere dense, so $X$ is a countable union of nowhere dense sets...

Comment: I agree! This this the way I followed to find this theorem!